# load the extension as Firefox starts

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, vscode-extensions, firefox-addon-webextensions, firefox-developer-tools

I am trying to load the extension in firefox which I have build in windows. Here I have downloaded the firefox nightly source code and made my own extension. Now, I want to load the extension as soon as  firefox starts. How to load the extension in firefox build ?

I tried to load the extension through some commands but it didn't work.

Comment: "I tried to load the extension through some commands but it didn't work." - That doesn't tell us anything.

Comment: Firstly I tried to create a profile. In that profile I loaded the extension and then tried to build firefox  again and used ./mach run --profile ./path of the profile. But by doing this my extension is not loaded.

Comment: "load extension asa firefox starts" - isn't extensions are already loaded after browser starts?